# X,Y, Z Coordinate

Tags: plotting, image-processing, coordinate

I require the X, Y and Z coordinates separately, in 3 different columns.
I have tried with, Table, Grid and Matrix.
Please let me have an idea how to perform it.
Thanks

```
image =;

cc = ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"];

imData = ImageData[cc];

TableForm[imData];

Grid[imData];

MatrixForm[imData];

ListPlot3D[imData]
```

Comment: Example code would help to give you an answer! Perhaps `Transpose[ ImageData[cc]]` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Removing the semicolons at the line ends could help.